# After update, android studio getting an error

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm facing one issue after updated my android studio. Android studion does't respond; it shows following error

When I select new project I got error like this:

> intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: jsr166e/extra/AtomicDouble [Plugin: io.sympli.idea.plugin]

and when I click on existing project I got error like this:

> Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: jsr166e/extra/AtomicDouble [Plugin: io.sympli.idea.plugin]

Any clue for these...?? any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Android Studio?

Comment: not yet but is it helpfull??

Comment: pro its time being process is there any other solution?

Comment: Yes. It will tell you if there was a problem with your original install or if there was a problem with the upgrade. Sometimes the upgrade doesn't work. When that happens, try to reinstall from scratch. You can backup your config files if you want to keep them.

Comment: Another idea is to disable the plugins. If you can open Android studio but not open a project then you should be able to access the plugins section to disable them.

Comment: yeah I'm able to open android studio but not any project or new project

Comment: Okay I'm trying

Comment: Are you sure about disable all plugins??

Comment: Just disable any that you think might be causing the problem. Anything that looks like it matches the error message. Otherwise disable them all and re-enable them later once it's working.

Comment: You can't switch the accepted answer like that. If you want to edit my answer to be more accurate you can do that. But you can't have someone post the same answer again, days later, and award the points to them. Please change this back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the offending plugin or reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: I tried and fortunately it working after disable sympli plugin... thank you Michael

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use the plugin, simply download their latest plugin:

https://sympli.io/downloads/androidstudio

Then in Android Studio, go to Preferences -> Plugins -> Install plugin from disk and select the downloaded zip and voila.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try deleting you .android folder. It should help, for me it worked or you can simply reinstall the android studio. Location is `C://users/yourname(or username of pc)/.android`

Comment: hi sid thanks for answering I appreciate it, but michael's answer works for me so I dont even tried your answer hope it will works for other